# Excel Insert Into Access Table from Excel defined Table with a Where Clause

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, insert, where-clause

A little stuck. I have a an excel table with lets say the following columns
[Date],[Name],[PostCode],[City]

And an access table with the same column names.

I'm trying to insert the excel data table into the access table but want to apply a WHERE clause so that it ignores dates already in the access table.

I can happily inset all data into the access table but cannot apply a WHERE clause successfully ignore the existing dates. And annoyingly I cant reference the actual table name correct so I am referencing the sheet (but works fine).

This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub TestInsert()

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

    Dim dbPath As String
    Dim xlPath As String
    Dim uSQL As String

    dbPath = "C:\Test\TestDB.accdb"
    xlPath = "C:\Test\TestXL.xlsm"

    'Set Connection string
    Set cnn = New Connection
    cnnstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

    'Open connection to db
    cnn.Open cnnstr

        uSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_ApolloBrochurewareReportTEST " _
            & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & xlPath & "].[Sheet1$]"


        cnn.Execute uSQL

    cnn.Close

End Sub
```

Any input or knowledge would be great, thank you.

Comment: If you place a unique index on the date field then duplicate records will simply be discarded. There should be this index anyway if there shouldn't be any duplicates, but a date field is rarely used as a unique field - dates aren't reliable for this purpose, any time element present will allow these *apparently* duplicated records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to expand the SQL expression:

```
    uSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_ApolloBrochurewareReportTEST " _
        & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & xlPath & "].[Sheet1$] As T " & _
        "WHERE T.Date NOT IN (SELECT [Date] FROM tbl_ApolloBrochurewareReportTEST)"
```

Comment: Thanks @gustav I'll give that go.

Comment: Worked a treat thank you. Cant believe I missed out just giving the excel table an alias. I was thinking too much about the VBA and not the SQL part. Thank you very much.