# Microsoft Access VBA to delete null rows?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm looking to build a VBA to delete the entire row of a table in access if a certain column is empty, lets call the column "services". This would have run on a loop so anytime data was added it would check, if possible. I am using an auto-generated ID in a different column if that changes anything. Thanks in advance

Comment: One doesn't interact with rows in a table inside of a loop. Instead you use SQL like `DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE services IS NULL;`. As far as how to trigger that each time a new row is inserted, I'll leave that to Access experts. I assume there is an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` event or trigger that can fire VBA?

Comment: Why use code for a procedural approach when plain old SQL works set-based and does exactly what you need? Not sure Access supports triggers... What is inserting in that table? If it's anybody anywhere, you need triggers. Otherwise, why wouldn't the code performing the insert ...not validate what it's inserting first?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'm importing data over from excel. In the excel sheet there an equation that is from A1:A1000 but only has data if another cell istext. So there is a ton of cell with "" in it and i didnt think access would pick up these blank cell but it is

Comment: If there's a formula in a cell, it's not an empty/blank cell, even if the formula is evaluating to an empty string, that's why. You could write a small procedure that prepares the worksheet for import by removing the rows that shouldn't be imported; it's always better to work upstream with sanitized data, than downstream to fix the data after the fact.

Comment: Not sure how you import the data from excel, but see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213791/excel-insert-into-access-table-from-excel-defined-table-with-a-where-clause. Just change the WHERE condition to exclude nulls.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon okay i will try that, any suggestions? Something to build in VBA for excel? I was looking for a function to do it earlier in this build but there is not one from my understanding

Comment: You can add a reference to the Excel object model in your Access project, and use it to manipulate the worksheet as needed - there are tons of examples on this site for conditionally deleting rows on a worksheet, but if the worksheet is laid out in plain rows & columns starting at R1C1 with consistent data types in each column then you can likely still use ODBC and SQL to filter out the rows you don't need, without involving the Excel object model at all.

Answer (score 0):

When importing the data into access from excel, modify your query to not pull any information when that cell is null.

If you are not using a query and just a range selection, I would loop through each row looking for the null value, if it is not null then copy the row to another sheet inside the excel workbook and export that worksheet once the loop is finished.

( I would have commented but do not have enough rep )